# Ubuntu Server Cannot Connect to Internet - Static IP

Tags: networking, server, internet

My home server (running Ubuntu Server 20.04) can't connect to the internet randomly. It was fine and then it wasn't (I made no changes to it). I am able to access it locally and through SSH locally. It can ping 8.8.8.8 and is set up with a static ip address. Running any sort of "sudo apt-get update" just returns a failed attempt.

Here is my netplan yaml setup:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno1]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.119/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
  version: 2
```

Here is the result of "sudo lshw -C network". The bridge is to a virtual machine that's off so that being disabled is normal.

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 94:de:80:b4:8f:0b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:f0500000-f051ffff memory:f053d000-f053dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:e8:cd:68
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Trying to ping google.com:

```
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Networ Logs "sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager":

```
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.6453] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.6454] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkMana>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.6482] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.fre>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.6699] manager[0x55640f84b040]: monitoring kernel f>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.6699] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8065] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8066] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "h>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8068] dns-mgr[0x55640f830290]: init: dns=systemd-r>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8070] manager[0x55640f84b040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardw>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8070] manager[0x55640f84b040]: rfkill: WWAN hardwa>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8153] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8235] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8294] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/l>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8312] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8356] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8358] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio kill>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8360] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio kills>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8361] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8362] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8385] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown (>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8385] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (i>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8385] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1649607668.8396] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/inter>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8428] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8430] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/free>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8437] device (br0): carrier: link connected
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8439] manager: (br0): new Bridge device (/org/free>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8446] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8448] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/f>
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1649607668.8541] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8606] manager: startup complete
Apr 10 11:21:08 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607668.8662] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Apr 10 11:21:09 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607669.6917] manager: (virbr0): new Bridge device (/org/f>
Apr 10 11:21:09 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607669.6947] manager: (virbr0-nic): new Tun device (/org/>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607987.3531] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607987.3540] device (eno1): released from master device b>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607987.3546] device (virbr0-nic): released from master de>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1649607987.3898] exiting (success)
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Succeeded.
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.4146] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.4147] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkMana>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.4186] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.fre>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.4208] manager[0x5633ae7e6030]: monitoring kernel f>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.4209] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5026] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5026] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "h>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5030] dns-mgr[0x5633ae7c8290]: init: dns=systemd-r>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5033] manager[0x5633ae7e6030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardw>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5033] manager[0x5633ae7e6030]: rfkill: WWAN hardwa>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5045] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5053] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5026] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5026] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "h>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5030] dns-mgr[0x5633ae7c8290]: init: dns=systemd-r>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5033] manager[0x5633ae7e6030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardw>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5033] manager[0x5633ae7e6030]: rfkill: WWAN hardwa>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5045] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5053] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5057] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/l>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5060] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5067] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/li>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5070] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio kill>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5071] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio kills>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5074] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5075] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5109] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown (>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5110] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (i>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5110] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <warn>  [1649607987.5110] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/inter>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5118] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5121] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/free>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5127] device (br0): carrier: link connected
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5129] manager: (br0): new Bridge device (/org/free>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5135] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5139] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/f>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5145] manager: (virbr0): new Bridge device (/org/f>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5150] manager: (virbr0-nic): new Tun device (/org/>
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <warn>  [1649607987.5153] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5172] manager: startup complete
Apr 10 11:26:27 homeserver NetworkManager[6077]: <info>  [1649607987.5236] modem-manager: ModemManager available
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. It seems to be fine from everything I can see but there's clearly a disconnect somewhere.

Edit: Additional research.

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

ls -al /etc/resolv.conf

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 24  2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

resolvectl status

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 5 (virbr0-nic)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 5 (virbr0-nic)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 4 (virbr0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (br0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      8.8.8.8

Link 2 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

Comment: "Ramdomly"? Insufficient investigation.Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: "just returns a failed attempt"? Just because you don't get any information from the exact error message is no reason to conceal it from those who might understand it.

Comment: Can you try ping "google.com" to see if DNS resolution is working?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema added as requested

Comment: @RamazanOz gives the error "ping: google.com: Name or service not known" - added to original post.

Comment: @waltinator I have added the logs to the original post.

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `resolvectl status`.

Comment: @heynnema added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this isn't an answer per-say but a reinstall of the OS (ubuntu server) fixed the problems. Ended up taking less time setting it up again than I've spent trying to trouble-shoot the actual problem. Nuclear option but with limited knowledge of what exactly went wrong, it was the easiest option.